# How to skip an iteration in FOR loop in uft

Tags: excel, for-loop, iteration, skip, vba

I am exporting two sheet from external excel sheet, sheet1 named as Global and sheet2 named as Data.

Global sheet contains login details and Data sheet contains multi inputs.

I have more than two rows in data sheet and want to skip the row (if pi=01) and run the next row in data sheet.

code:

```
case 51

if processindicator = 01 then 
ExitActionIteration
Else
"statement"
End If
```

but it is skipping all iteration instead of current iteration

help me to resolve this and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not see all of your code it is hard to tell. But maybe the following example is what you're looking for. Basically, it will go from 1 to 100 and merely skips the number 51:

```
Public Sub TestSkippingOfAnIteration()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 100
    If i = 51 Then i = i + 1
    Debug.Print i
Next i

End Sub
```

Let me know if that solves your problem. Otherwise, please elaborate and post all of your relevant code.

Comment: ... `Then Exit For`. But then again: why would I have the `For` run from 1 to 100 and not to 99 instead? After all, all exceptions are hard coded into the VBA sub and not dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the conditional code in an `If` statement:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    ...
    If processIndicator <> 1 Then
        '// do whatever you want here
    End If
Next
```

or (less advised, as it decreases readability and logic) use a `GoTo` statement:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    ...
    If processIndicator = 1 Then
        GoTo Skip_Line:
    Else
        '// do whatever you want here
    End If
    ...

Skip_Line:
Next
```

Comment: In the second way it is unnecessary to provide `Else`. An immediate `End If`would at least lead to less indentation.

Comment: A single line `If` statement would be even better, I've just written it that way to try and make the logic a bit clearer as to how one can navigate around within a loop. It's not intended to be used as working code.